# How configure Qt Creator to compile qupzilla?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.1

Is there any simple way to configure Qt Creator to compile qupzilla in my folder (not in /usr/bin and /usr/lib)?

By default i get "error: ../../bin/libQupZilla.so". If i set the path to my app folder with ldconfig - app is compiled but without plugins. They return errors for example (build/qrc_testplugin.cpp Error 1 or something with locale folder).

OS: Arch Linux 64 bit

QT: Qt5

Also i successfully compile qupzilla-git from AUR with qt5. This means that my problem somewhere in incorrect settings or paths...

Qupzilla: http://www.qupzilla.com/

---

Solution:
1) Add path to programm "path_to_app/bin" to ldconfig (/etc/ld.so.conf)

2) Check off in Projects "Shadow build" checkbox.

3) Change qmake to qmake-qt5. If I understand correctly, it is not necessary to do. Since in Arch Linux qmake and qmake-qt5 same.

4) In build environment add

```
KDE       true
USE_WEBGL true
```

Comment: First, link to home page in question would be nice. Then, can you compile it from command line in the same environment?

Comment: I add link. I compile it with the same environment as package (make some changes to qt5) https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qupzilla-git/ . Now I will test a compile from the command line

Comment: Compilation from command line was successfully completed. If i remove path from ldconfig - program can't work. But if i add path to lib's in ldconfig - programm run and work. Plugins are successfully compiled too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `libQupZilla` (or any library) somewhere else than system library directories, easiest is to edit the `.pro` file, add line like:

```
LIBS += -L$(PWD)/..relative-path-to-library-location../
```

...or use absolute path to the library if you want. You probably already have `-lQupZilla` there, so no need to add that the 2nd time.

---

In general, with problems like this in Qt Creator, look at the *Compile Output* tab (at the bottom of the screen). Find the link command (note: if project uses cmake instead of qmake, you *may* need to add some switches or something for that to make the command visible), which is the one with all the `-L/path` and `-lfoobar` switches, and `-o programname` outputting the final target. Then look earlier to see in what directory it is being run in. Then look if everything matches, and possibly try to copy-paste and run the command from command line yourself, in the same directory where it is run when building under Qt Creator.